# Pegar valor de uma campo na view em uma controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Pelas respostas aqui, não consegui pegar. Tenho essa view

```
    @{
    ViewBag.Title = "ExcelFinancing";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        .embaixo {
            position: absolute;
            left: 0;
            bottom: 20%;
            width: auto;
            bottom: auto;
            top: 50%;
            margin: 10%,10%,10%,10%;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h3 class="page-header fa-align-center">@ViewBag.TitlePage</h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    @*<div class="panel panel-default">*@

    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.Label("De")
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.datefinancing, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", ID = "dataIni" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.datefinancing, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-1">
            @Html.Label("Até")
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.datefinancing, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", ID = "dataFim" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.datefinancing, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field col s3">
            <div>

                <p>
                    @{string Todos = ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("Todos");}
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.statussolicitation, "Todos", new { id = Todos, name = "imp_tx_tipo", value = "Todos", @class = "with-gap" })
                    <label for="Todos">Todos</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    @{string Ativos = ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("Ativos");}
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.statussolicitation, "Ativos", new { id = Ativos, name = "imp_tx_tipo", value = "Ativos", @class = "with-gap" })
                    <label for="Ativos">Ativos</label>
                </p>
                <p>
                    @{string Inativos = ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldId("Inativos");}
                    @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.statussolicitation, "Inativos", new { id = Inativos, name = "imp_tx_tipo", value = "Ativos", @class = "with-gap" })
                    <label for="Inativos">Inativos</label>
                </p>
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.statussolicitation, "", new { @class = "red-text text-darken-2" })

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("geraExcel1", "FinancingReport", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <div class="input-group">
                <div class="input-group-btn">
                    <input type="submit" value="Gerar Relatório" class="btn btn-primary" />
                </div>
            </div>
        }

</body>
</html>
```

Essa é minha controller

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult geraExcel1()
    {
        var context = new SyngentaBenefitsEntities();
        var model = new SolicitationViewModel();

        //var teste = dataFim;

        geraExcel();
        ViewBag.TitlePage = "Relatório de Financiamento";
        return null; 
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult geraExcel()
    {  
        List<vwFinancingReportViewModel> lista = new List<vwFinancingReportViewModel>();
        lista = dadosPlanilha();

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.Append("Status;Nro.Pessoal;Nome Completo;Grade;Nro.Solicitação;Data Financiamento;" + 
            "Ano Fabric.;Modelo;Chassi;Valor Bem;Valor Financiado;Status Solicitação;Status Pagamento;" +
            "Valor Parcela;Juros;ReembolsoKM;Reembolso Depreciação\r\n");
        foreach(var item in lista)
        {
            sb.Append(item.employeestatus.ToString() + ";" + item.employeeid.ToString() + ";" + item.fullname.ToString() + ";" +
                      item.grade.ToString() + ";" + item.solicitationid.ToString() + ";" + item.datefinancing.ToString() + ";" +
                      item.manufacturer.ToString() + ";" + item.model.ToString() + ";" + item.chassi.ToString() + ";" +
                      item.valueproperty.ToString() + ";" + item.valuegranted.ToString() + ";" + item.statussolicitation.ToString() + ";" +
                      item.paymentstatus.ToString() + ";" + item.valuepayment.ToString() + ";" +
                      item.valueinterest.ToString() + ";" + item.refundkm.ToString() + ";" +
                      item.refund.ToString() + "\r\n");

        }
        //sb.Append("Eduardo;11111\r\n");
        //sb.Append("Coutinho;22222\r\n");

        HttpContext.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename=" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + "ReportFinanciamentoRH.csv"));

        HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/CSV";
        HttpContext.Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default;

        HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);

        HttpContext.Response.Write(sb.ToString());

        HttpContext.Response.End();

        return null;
    }
```

Na view eu tenho um campo DateTime, onde seria um filtro para meu sql, que seria DataInicio e DataFim. Acontece que eu não estou sabendo enviar para a controller esses valores, para que eu possa usá-los na minha query.

Comment: você pode passar o valor pelow ViewBag.NomeDavariavel ou  Pelo Model

Comment: @MarcosBrinner, mas da View para a Controller usando ViewBag? Achei quye só o contrário era possível. Eu tenho um formulário e preciso pegar o valor dele no meu controller

Comment: A sim agora compreendi sua pergunta então, você está usando  POST ou GET para enviar os dados ?:

Comment: Pode passar pela Model quando postar, ou via ajax...

Comment: Só uma dúvida, só preciso dos valores de duas datas para alimentar um método(parametros). Tenho que submeter o formulário? Sei que é básico, mas tenho essa dúvida.

Comment: sim, se  esses valores estiverem vindo do cliente-side você precisa envialos de alguma forma para o servidor, você também pode passar pela url ao que carrega a view

Comment: tipo site.com/controller/action?DataFim=18/06/2069

Comment: Ok, minha action é HttpPost e o botão submit se encarrega de enviar o form. Mas como eu faço agora, tipo, **var teste = ?????** como carrego a var teste? Essa é a dúvida. Dessa forma não vai: **var teste = dataFim.Value;** apenas um exemplo hipotético.

Comment: @MarcosBrinner, como eu passo pela url esses valores ao carregar a view?

Comment: A pergunta não está clara, por favor, dê uma pesquisada melhor sobre o assunto e formate melhor sua dúvida (exemplo: adicione a View para entendermos melhor como está sendo feito o post da página, atualize o código com o HttpPost na Action, etc...) para que possamos ajudá-lo.

Comment: Já tentou colocar tudo dentro de "@using(Html" e passar por parâmetro seu model no método post?

Comment: @LucasRiechelmannRamos, não tentei fazer isso, para dizer a verdade, nem pensei nisso.

Comment: Em nenhuma das actions você está esperando algum valor?

Comment: @LucasRiechelmannRamos, você tinha razão. Renan, valeu pelo "puxão de orelha". Se o Lucas responder, eu marco a resposta.

Comment: @pnet então atualize o código da pergunta para fazer sentido com a resposta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Coloca todo o seu form dentro de

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("geraExcel1", "FinancingReport", FormMethod.Post))
```

e utiliza o model para passar como parâmetro no método post

```
public ActionResult geraExcel1(Model model)
{
    ....
}
```